# Ajax error load Url from remote server in phonegap

Tags: ajax, cordova

I have been develop Phonegap android App. I put folder www in remote server, and in MainActivity(DroidGap) i loadUrl from server. I had config in Phonegap and App running in device ( load and show page from server). But problem when i send request by Ajax to server then it fail. It could not connect to any host. Please help me? Thanh you so much.
  - MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("http://172.16.3.198:8080/ServerMail/index.html");    
}
```

- Config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>

<content src="http://172.16.3.198:8080/ServerMail/index.html" />
```

Answer (score 1):

the app does not have the internet permission.  you can edit AndroidManifest.xml， and something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.petro"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have your 'site' files local to the app, not on a remote server, otherwise there is little point to Phonegap.

Here you might find that your URL is simply not reachable.  A 172.16.x.x address is local to the network the server is hosted on, perhaps your phone is not on that network, especially if you are using 3G to connect.

Also, bare in mind that depending on the phone you use, you may be using an old version of webkit.  As I've developed Phonegap apps, I have run into problems with jQuery 2 and older Android releases (2.1 for example).  It seems to me that what you're doing is not a good use of Phonegap, and you might be better off using a shortcut instead.

Comment: Thanks Henry Blackman. I understand that. Problem is i use ajax in client to service in other domain( Cross domain) and it fail. I have try many way but it not success. Anyone have a any idea to solve problem. I want to put all content of app in server because i want to update app whenever i needed. And my app is dynamically, as website.